# istream operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm trying to do a simple istream operator overloading, but for some reason, once entering this function, the program enters an infinite loop.
please help!

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 class date{

int m_day,m_month,m_year;

public:

date(int day=1,int month=1,int year=2000){    //constructor
    if (day>0 && day<32 && month>0 && month<13){
        m_day =day;
        m_month=month;
        m_year=year;
    }
}


friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const date& d);
friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const date& d);
};


istream& operator>> (istream& stream, const date& d){              //overload >>
stream >> d.m_day;
return stream;

}

void main(){  

date date1;

cin>>date1;                   //check istream

getchar();
}
```

Comment: Funny, since there are no loops in your code.

Comment: what loop are you talking about ? Have you tried to debug, have you tried to put traces to see/understand what is happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code seems wrong to me, since you are trying to modify a `const` object (d).

```
istream& operator>> (istream& stream, const date& d){              //overload >>
    stream >> d.m_day;
    return stream;    
}
```

Comment: when i said loop i meant it went back and forth between the line: stream >> d.m_day;
and the line:                                                   istream& operator>> (istream& stream, const date& d){

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer by Marc does not solve your problem completely. What is happenning is a bit more complicated:

You defined the function receiving a `const &`. That should have made the compiler simply refuse to compile your function. But here lies the problem: your constructor for `date` has default values for every parameter. Therefore, it can be called with only one parameter. Since it is not marked `explicit`, it works as an implicit conversion operator for an int (like `date(i)`). This means the compiler can interpret `stream >> d.m_day` as `stream >> date(d.m_day)`. Your problem thus was: this is a call for `operator>>(istream& stream, const date& d)` and you get an infinite recursion.

Thus, you should not only make `date& d` non-const on your overload of `operator>>`, you should also mark the constructor `explicit`, like

```
explicit date(int day=1, int month=1, int year=2000)
```

so that it doesn't act as an implicit conversion operator. This should be done, actually, to almost every constructor that can possibly take only one parameter.

Comment: possibly better to simply remove the defaults ie date(int day, int month, int year).  Even then a date can be initialised with an invalid date - could raise exception in that case.