# ">> no operator found which takes a left-hand operator of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a dynamic array, then fill that array using the text from an input file but I keep getting this error. I looked for an answer for hours but they all seem to get into vectors. I also don't think I am missing any libraries.

```
int main()
{
    // Parameter - Instance 1
    Grocery g1("NA", 0, "NA");
    g1.setName("Milk");
    g1.setQuant("1");
    g1.setUnit("Bottle");

    Grocery g2(g1); // Calls copy constructor

    // Default constructor - Instance 3
    //Grocery g3(); 

    // Operator =
    Grocery g4;
    cout << "Operator = Running" << endl;
    g4 = g2;
    cout << g4.getName() << endl;
    cout << g4.getQuant() << endl;
    cout << g4.getUnit() << endl << endl;


    // Operator <<
    cout << "Operator<< Running" << endl;
    Grocery g5("Salt", "1", "Teaspoon");
    cout << g5 << endl;
    //cout << g5.getName();
    //cout << g5.getQuant();
    //cout << g5.getUnit();


    // Dynamic Array of Grocery
    Grocery* groceryArray;
    groceryArray = new Grocery[3];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("fileName.txt");


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> groceryArray[i].setName;
        cout >> groceryArray[i].setName;
    }

    inputFile.close();
    delete[]groceryArray;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//Grocery.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Grocery
{
private:
    string* m_name;
    string* m_quant;
    string* m_unit;

public:
    Grocery(); // Default constructor
    Grocery(string n, string q, string u); // Parametered constructor
    ~Grocery(); // Destructor
    Grocery(const Grocery& rhs); // Copy constructor
    Grocery& operator=(const Grocery& rhs); // Operator=
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Grocery& rhs); //Operator>>
    string getName();
    void setName(string n);

    string getQuant();
    void setQuant(string q);

    string getUnit();
    void setUnit(string u);

};
```

When ran it I got two errors:
Error C2676 binary '>>': 'std::ostream' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: There are no declaration of `Grocery` given, but I guess that `getXxxx` series are functions while the righthand operand should be data variables. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `getName`, `getQuant` and `getUnit` look like setter member functions, did you forget to call them, or are they really variable names of `Grocery`?

Comment: Need to see the definition of `Grocery`. A complete error message would help as well.

Comment: @Kaldrr getName seems like a getter not a setter. I think the OP is confused.

Comment: Meant to make the setters not getters sorry. I’ve also added the Grocery definition to the post and will put in the rest of the main function

Answer (score 1):

In C++ in order to get input from user straight into an object you must apply >> operator see the example below operator >> get monomial from string

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Monomial& mon){
    char str[SIZE];
    cin.getline(str, SIZE);
    mon.updateMonomialString(str, mon.coefficientNum, mon.degreeNum);

    return input;
}
```

read more on operator >> implementation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610586/istream-operator-overloading-c)

Another thing `getters` should return strings/info etc. 
And `setters` should set the values/objects etc.

Comment: Not knowing the specification of `mon.updateMonomialString`, generally using [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read into `std::string` should be better because there is no explicit line size limit then.

Comment: mon.updateMonomialString is a function to retrieve monomial from user input(char*) ,it was an assignment on my degree with the limitation of not using string only chars.

Comment: In the program I actually the used the operator>> on a previous function (I've added to the original post). I was told to use both the operator>> and operator=, but not to use operator<< for this.

Comment: Seems like your missing operator >> (handle input) , I see you have operator  << (handle output)